# AWS and Magento 2 Owner of the files and folders

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, magento2

I installed Magento 2 using Amazon Web Services, i did it in:

/var/www/html/

It mean you can find the app directory in:

/var/www/html/app/

I don't really know if is better create directories like

/var/www/html/public_html/my_proyect/app...

But it's not the most important

The important thing is, what user must i set in the folders, must be the html folder the same user:group that the magento2 folders and files.

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The premise is:

"All directories should be 755 and files can either be 644 or 664"

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 640 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 750 {} \;
chmod -R g+w /var/www/magento2/{pub,var}
```

If it doesn't works:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```